# Does the electric displacement field account for free charges?

Tags: electromagnetism, conductors

I'm trying to understand the electric displacement field $\mathbf{D}$ for a lossy material with conductivity $\sigma$ and permittivity $\epsilon$.

Most textbooks I've looked at only consider perfect dielectrics when discussing $\mathbf{D}$.
However, the first two sentences of the [Wikipedia article on $\mathbf{D}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_displacement_field) state

> In physics, the **electric displacement field** (denoted by **D**) or **electric induction** is a vector field that appears in Maxwell's equations. It accounts for the effects of free and bound charge within materials.

But then in the next section (as in most textbooks), $\mathbf{D}$ is defined as
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{D} = \epsilon_0\mathbf{E} + \mathbf{P}.\tag{1}\label{eq}
\end{align}
Now clearly $\mathbf{P}$ accounts for only bound charges. So what accounts for free charges? If the Wikipedia quote is indeed true, shouldn't $\sigma$ appear somewhere in (\ref{eq})?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Displacement field $\mathbf D$ is defined by
$$
\mathbf D = \epsilon_0 \mathbf E + \mathbf P.
$$

Statement "accounts for the effects of free and bound charge" is a weird, probably incorrect statement, because just giving values of components of $D_x, D_y, D_z$ in some region of space does not give us enough information on the bound charge. It does give us information on free charge, because its density obeys the equation

$$
\nabla \cdot \mathbf D = \rho_f
$$
or in other way
$$
\frac{\partial D_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial D_y}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial D_z}{\partial z} = \rho_f.
$$

A correct statement would be that value of $\mathbf D$ at some point of space is influenced both by free and bound charge. This is because (in electrostatics) $\mathbf E$ is function of total charge density in all space, and $\mathbf P$ is function of how bound charge density is shifted from its neutral position (and in the simple cases, can be determined from bound charge distribution and boundary conditions for $\mathbf P$).